# Why am I not getting a value to for my return statements?

Tags: python

Why am I not getting a value to print for my function "fridgees"?

```
f = int(input("Enter the number of fridges in your house: ")) 
def fridgees(f): 
    if f == 0:
        fridges = 0
    if f > 0: 
        fridges = 0
        while fridges <= f:
            fridges = fridges + 1
            return(fridges)
        
print(fridgees)
```

Comment: You're printing the function `fridgees`. You're not *executing* the function, which might be something like `print(fridgees(f))`.

Answer (score 0):

what your code does is prints the function not executing it
always to execute a function use this **Function()** and not this **Function**

```
f = int(input("Enter the number of fridges in your house: ")) 
def fridgees(f):
    if f == 0:
        fridges = 0
    if f > 0: 
        fridges = 0
        while fridges <= f:
            fridges = fridges + 1
            return fridges
print(fridgees(f))
```